# No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

Tags: websocket, cdi, java-websocket

when I run this code I go this error

> No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped

any help please , what should I do?
I'm using this code to do chatting between different user so I'm the servlet bean extract different connected user

```java
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@RequestScoped
@Named
public class ServletBean implements Serializable{


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    /**
     * 
     */
    @Inject
    CompanyController  companyController;
    @Inject
    CandidateController candidateController;
    private int id;
    private int idCandidate;
    @PostConstruct
    public void display(){
        ELContext elContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getELContext();
        companyController = (CompanyController) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getELResolver()
                .getValue(elContext, null, "companyController");
        ELContext elContext1 = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getELContext();
        candidateController = (CandidateController) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getApplication().getELResolver()
                .getValue(elContext1, null, "candidateController");
        if (companyController.getIdCompany()!= 0) {
            id=companyController.getIdCompany();
        }
        if (candidateController.getConnectedCandidate().getIdUserInformation()!=0) {
            id = candidateController.getConnectedCandidate().getIdUserInformation();
        }


        System.out.println("ligne 11+id1"+id+idCandidate);
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getIdCandidate() {
        return idCandidate;
    }
    public void setIdCandidate(int idCandidate) {
        this.idCandidate = idCandidate;
    }
}

@ServerEndpoint(value = "/websocket/{client-id}")
public class MyServerEndpoint {

    private static final LinkedList<Session> clients = new LinkedList<Session>();
    @Inject
    ServletBean servletBean;
    @Inject
    ChatlogBean chatlogBean;
    ChatLog chatLog;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
    System.out.println("ligne 26"+  session.getUserPrincipal()+"*******"+session.getId());

    clients.add(session);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message,
            @PathParam("client-id") String clientId) {
        for (Session client : clients) {
            try {
                client.getBasicRemote().sendObject(clientId + ": " + message);
                System.out.println("ligne 26 message" + message + "clientId"
                        + clientId);
                System.out.println("ligne 57"+servletBean.getId());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (EncodeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session peer) {
        clients.remove(peer);
    }

}
```

Comment: Just clean and rebuild your project, then run it.

Comment: it didn't work  i clened the project and no result

Comment: yes but no result this one work on @applicationscoped but i need the viewscoped because i need rather then one user connected

Comment: It used to happen to me too, I just closed the browser, cleaned and rebuilt the project and it went away. Didn't know why it started happening, I did not have it happen before though.

Comment: no result i'm using wildfly 8.2

Comment: try using the newest version of wildfly, 10.1 I think is the latest one

Comment: @steve.vai, have you tried lowering your scope? It appears like you're not within an active period of a request context. Try using `@Dependent`.

Comment: i tried it it doesn't work

Comment: Is it deployment error? How do you access this bean? Take a look at the description of RequestScoped annotation: https://docs.jboss.org/cdi/api/1.0-SP1/javax/enterprise/context/RequestScoped.html It describes when the context is active.